# Problem after installing and linking Firebase problem

Tags: react-native

I just installed and linked firebase to my react-native project,
here's the problem that happens during "**react-native run-android**",

### Here's my settings.gradle file :

```
rootProject.name = 'bASICS'
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-firebase\android')

include ':app'
```

---

### Here's the error I am getting :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
>   Settings file 'E:\React-Native\bASICS\E\New\android\settings.gradle' line: 3
>
> What went wrong:
>   Could not compile settings file 'E:\React-Native\bASICS\E\New\android\settings.g
>   radle'.
>   startup failed:
>     settings file 'E:\React-Native\bASICS\E\New\android\settings.gradle': 3: unexp
>   ected char: '\' @ line 3, column 119.
>        _modules\react-native-firebase\android')

---

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23176

Answer (score 1):

Try by replacing your third line:

```
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-firebase\android')
```

with the following code:

```
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
```

Hope will resolve your problem.